# Solving a fraction with shown work

Tags: fractions

I'm sitting here scratching my head and wondering what I'm missing. So here are is fraction like questions that I don't fully grasp. I gotten the answer with help of calculator ***a b/c*** function, but I would love if someone could break down the actual solution method.

> 18 feet - 9 inches 7/16 inch - 6 feet - 4 inches 15/16 inch
>
> = 12 feet - 4 inches 1/2 inch
>
> or
>
> 18' - 9 7/16" - 6' 4 15/16"
>
> = 12' - 4 1/2"

Here I's what I can't quite understand. How does **9 7/16" - 4 15/16"** becomes **4 1/2".**

Because I can't minus **7** from **15** I would need to borrow a "***1***" from the **9**. So we get 17. Now **17 - 15 = 2**. So in theory it should be **2/16**, now to bring that down we divide by 2 and the end result is **1/8**.

Because we took a "***1***" from the **9** it's **8 - 4 = 4** so based on this the end solution must be

> 1**2 feet - 4 inches 1/8 inch**

But this is not what I get if I use the ***a b/c*** function of my calculator. So what am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$9\ \frac{7}{16}-4\ \frac{15}{16}=8\ \frac{23}{16}-4\ \frac{15}{16}=4\ \frac{8}{16}=4\ \frac{1}{2}.$

What you did wrong is that when you carried the 1 over, you get $1+\frac{7}{16}=\frac{16+7}{16}=\frac{23}{16},$ not $\frac{17}{16}.$

Comment: How did you get 8 23/16?

Comment: 9 7/16=8+(1 7/16). And 1 7/16 is 23/16 as the second line states.

Comment: So since we take away 1 from the 9 we get 1 7/16. Because 1 technically is 16/16 so we get 16/16 + 7/16 which gives us 23/16?

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean!

Comment: Thank you. Figured it out now with your help, Math is one of those subjects where to got to get the good old brain kicking lol.